# I'm having a fragment, how can I display it as a navigation drawer like view on an image press open and close the fragment animation in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm having a fragment, how can I display it as a navigation drawer like view on an image press open and close the fragment animation?

So on an image icon press open the fragment from left to right and again clicking on image move the fragment right to left and hide it like a navigation drawer
Is it possible to do that?